# Generating same plots in all subplot graphs

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I want to extract 30 random data entries from the dataframe and plot them separately in 3*10 subplots. In order to do so, I used iterations but all 30 data entries were plotted in all 30 subplots.Can anyone help me to figure it out?

```
sample = random.sample(range(0, len(data)), 30)

array = data.to_numpy()

fig, ax = plt.subplots(3,10, figsize=(10,10))

for row in range(0,3):

  for column in range(0,10):

    for i in sample:

      tb = array[i][1:]

      tb = list(map(int, tb))

      x = list(range(1990,2008))

      ax[row,column].plot(x,tb)
```

Comment: Please format your code. You can use three backticks ``` before and after your code

Comment: you can use seaborn to create your plot and subplots. The option 'ax' allows you to specify the matplotlib axis. you can see examples here: https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.distplot.html

Comment: Are you trying to plot a single point in 30 different sub-plots, or 30 samples from 1990 to 2008?

Comment: I am trying to plot 30 sets of data from 1990 to 2008 in 30 plots respectively.